# Custom floats are not labeled correctly in the listof or text references

Tags: floats, formatting, lists, labels

I'm new to StackExchange and LaTeX. I am using a custom float for "schemes" using the caption package. The problem I'm having is that the label "Scheme" does not show up when using the \ref command in text, nor does it show up in the list. I have posted a MWE below:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[listformat=simple]{caption}

\DeclareCaptionType[name=Scheme,within=section]{scheme}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listofscheme

\newpage

\section{new section}
This is a new section with \ref{sch:1}.
\begin{scheme}
    \begin{center}
        \caption{\label{sch:1}This is a scheme.}
        \rule[-1mm]{8mm}{1cm}
    \end{center}
\end{scheme}

\section{Another section}
Testing \ref{sch:2}.
\begin{scheme}
    \begin{center}
        \caption{\label{sch:2}This is a another scheme.}
        \rule[-1mm]{20mm}{1cm}
    \end{center}
\end{scheme}

\end{document}
```

The List of Schemes only has the scheme numbers, but I want "Scheme" prefixed to the number to say "Scheme 1.1"

If I use the `\ref` command in text, I get a similar problem; it only shows the number, not the "Scheme" label. If I can change my code or message to be more meaningful, let me know since I'm a n00b. Additionally, I cannot use the `tocloft` package; it does not mesh with the thesis template from my school. The template does not affect the results, I get the same thing from the MWE as I do from my full document using the template. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: `\ref` usually gives back the number. I guess you are looking for something like `\autoref` provided by package `hyperref`. You might need to set this up tough, not sure.

Comment: I didn't realize that, I guess my thesis template automatically takes care of that with Figures and Tables. But since Schemes are my own addition, it doesn't do that. If I use `\autoref` with `hyperref` instead of `\ref`, the text references are fixed but the \listofschemes is still missing the "Scheme" label.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by `cleveref` and with its `\cref/\Cref` macros.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[listformat=simple]{caption}

\DeclareCaptionType[name=Scheme,within=section]{scheme}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{scheme}{scheme}{schemes}
\Crefname{scheme}{Scheme}{Schemes}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listofscheme

\newpage

\section{new section}
This is a new section with \cref{sch:1}.
\begin{scheme}
    \begin{center}
        \caption{\label{sch:1}This is a scheme.}
        \rule[-1mm]{8mm}{1cm}
    \end{center}
\end{scheme}

\section{Another section}
Testing \cref{sch:2}.
\begin{scheme}
    \begin{center}
        \caption{\label{sch:2}This is a another scheme.}
        \rule[-1mm]{20mm}{1cm}
    \end{center}
\end{scheme}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This will fix the references in text. Do you know how to get the `\listofscheme` to Say "Scheme 1.1" instead of just "1.1"?

Comment: You could try hacking down your template till you find how it adds the words `Figure`/`table` to the respective lists and adapt this to your schemes.

Comment: But think about the reason, that this is not default. What do you expect in a *List of figures*? Why adding the expected over and over again.

Comment: May be you can provide a link to your template.

Comment: I will try to find where `Figure` and `Table` are added, though looking at the code, it may be a little beyond my skill level. The reason it's not the default is that the template is a work in progress; the programmer was a student and he can't cover all possibilities. While schemes are common in chemistry, they are not common in all sciences. That programmer has graduated, and no one has picked up the work since. Here is a link to the site: [template link](http://www.compholio.com/csm/csm-thesis/)
I am using just the template, not the fully documented version.