# custom listof with endash separator

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, captions, floatrow

I'm using [`floatrow`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow?lang=en) to create a new environment `Quadros` (it means frames) but despite showing the correct separator within caption the List Of Quadros still displays a empty space instead. Just need the endash after the float number. I did search for [similar questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187694/custom-floats-are-not-labeled-correctly-in-the-listof-or-text-references) but couldn't find anything that fixed my problem.

**Edit 2:** To keep up with my thesis layout I'v adpated C. Hupfer solution into this :

`\DeclareCaptionListFormat{quadro}{\llap{{#1}}{#2}\hfill\rlap{\textendash}\hfill\hspace{0.5em}}`

Displays exactly like the default list of figure, except by a pixel or two but that's probably due to microtype or simply different characters.

**Edit**: the current solution from C. Hupfer:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\l@quadro}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{1.7em}}
\makeatother
```

Leads me to problems with the double digit floats:

[image]

I'v tried to add a `\hspace{0.15em}` before the `\textendash` but doesn't work properly either.

[image: Endash after float number]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\let\newfloat\relax                     % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
\let\tmp\newinsert                      % 
\let\newinsert\newbox                   % This is to fix some bug of floatrow
\usepackage{floatrow}                   %
\let\newinsert\tmp                      % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
\floatsetup{objectset=centering,capposition=top}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareNewFloatType{quadro}{placement=p,fileext=frm,name=Quadro}
\newcommand*{\quadroautorefname}{quadro}
\captionsetup[quadro]{
   name=Quadro,
   justification=justified,
   position=above,
   skip=\onelineskip,
   width=0.95\linewidth,
   labelsep=endash, %% ABNT thing requires to use dash
   labelfont={small},
   font={footnotesize},
}
\begin{document}

\begingroup
\let\oldnumberline\numberline
\renewcommand{\numberline}{Quadro~\oldnumberline}
\listof{quadro}{ Lista de Quadros}
\endgroup

    \begin{quadro}
\caption{aaa}\label{quad:a}
content...
\end{quadro}
\begin{quadro}
\caption{bbb}\label{quad:b}
content...
\end{quadro}

\begin{quadro}
\caption{aaa}\label{quad:a}
content...
\end{quadro}
\begin{quadro}
\caption{bbb}\label{quad:b}
content...
\end{quadro}
\begin{quadro}
\caption{aaa}\label{quad:a}
content...
\end{quadro}
\begin{quadro}
\caption{bbb}\label{quad:b}
content...
\end{quadro}
\begin{quadro}
\caption{aaa}\label{quad:a}
content...
\end{quadro}
\begin{quadro}
\caption{bbb}\label{quad:b}
content...
\end{quadro}
\begin{quadro}
\caption{aaa}\label{quad:a}
content...
\end{quadro}
\begin{quadro}
\caption{bbb}\label{quad:b}
content...
\end{quadro}
\begin{quadro}
\caption{aaa}\label{quad:a}
content...
\end{quadro}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `endash` setup in `labelsep` is only for printing the caption where the float appears, but not for the `List of ....`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a built-in support for providing specialized `list-of` formats in `caption` package with the setup

```
\DeclareCaptionListFormat{quadro}{#1\textendash\ #2}
```

and using `listformat=quadro` in `\captionsetup`.

The name `quadro` is arbitrary (as long it's not `figure` etc. )

Since the spacing after the quadro number may be too wide the `\l@quadro` macro must be redefined.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\l@quadro}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{1.7em}}
\makeatother
```

The last parameter (the one with `1.7em`) contains the `numwidth`, i.e. the width of the number section. Usually, this is `2.3em`, I reduced it to `1.7em`.

```
    \documentclass{memoir}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \let\newfloat\relax                     % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
%    \let\tmp\newinsert                      % 
%    \let\newinsert\newbox                   % This is to fix some bug of floatrow
    \usepackage{floatrow}                   %
%    \let\newinsert\tmp                      % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
    \floatsetup{objectset=centering,capposition=top}



\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareNewFloatType{quadro}{placement=p,fileext=frm,name=Quadro}
\DeclareCaptionListFormat{quadro}{#1#2 \textendash}

\newcommand*{\quadroautorefname}{quadro}
\captionsetup[quadro]{
   name=Quadro,
   justification=justified,
   position=above,
   skip=\onelineskip,
   width=0.95\linewidth,
   labelsep=endash, %% ABNT thing requires to use dash
   labelfont={small},
   font={footnotesize},
   listformat=quadro
}


\begin{document}

\begingroup
\let\oldnumberline\numberline
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\l@quadro}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{1.7em}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\numberline}{Quadro~\oldnumberline}
\listof{quadro}{ Lista de Quadros}
\endgroup

\begin{quadro}
\caption{aaa}\label{quad:a}
content...
\end{quadro}
\begin{quadro}
\caption{bbb}\label{quad:b}
content...
\end{quadro}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

I've added a `\llap` statement in the definition of the list format. The `\renewcommand{\l@quadro}`... isn't necessary any longer then, since aligning the quadro number to the right boundary requires more horizontal spacing than `1.7em`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\let\newfloat\relax                     % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
\usepackage{floatrow}                   %
\floatsetup{objectset=centering,capposition=top}



\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareNewFloatType{quadro}{placement=p,fileext=frm,name=Quadro}

\DeclareCaptionListFormat{quadro}{\hfill#1\hfill\llap{#2}\hfill\textendash\hfill}

\newcommand*{\quadroautorefname}{quadro}
\captionsetup[quadro]{
   name=Quadro,
   justification=justified,
   position=above,
   skip=\onelineskip,
   width=0.95\linewidth,
   labelsep=endash, %% ABNT thing requires to use dash
   labelfont={small},
   font={footnotesize},
   listformat=quadro
}


\begin{document}

\begingroup
\let\oldnumberline\numberline
\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*{\l@quadro}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.7em}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\numberline}{Quadro~\oldnumberline}
\listof{quadro}{ Lista de Quadros}
\endgroup


\begin{quadro}
\caption{aaa}\label{quad:a}
content...
\end{quadro}
  \begin{quadro}
  \caption{bbb}%\label{quad:\x}
  content...
\end{quadro}

  \begin{quadro}
  \caption{bbb}%\label{quad:\x}
  content...
\end{quadro}

  \begin{quadro}
  \caption{bbb}%\label{quad:\x}
  content...
\end{quadro}

  \begin{quadro}
  \caption{bbb}%\label{quad:\x}
  content...
\end{quadro}

  \begin{quadro}
  \caption{bbb}%\label{quad:\x}
  content...
\end{quadro}

  \begin{quadro}
  \caption{bbb}%\label{quad:\x}
  content...
\end{quadro}

  \begin{quadro}
  \caption{bbb}%\label{quad:\x}
  content...
\end{quadro}

  \begin{quadro}
  \caption{bbb}%\label{quad:\x}
  content...
\end{quadro}

  \begin{quadro}
  \caption{bbb}%\label{quad:\x}
  content...
\end{quadro}

  \begin{quadro}
  \caption{bbb}%\label{quad:\x}
  content...
\end{quadro}

  \begin{quadro}
  \caption{bbb}%\label{quad:\x}
  content...
\end{quadro}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you shouldn't need the newinsert dance with the latest latex (floatrow bug is still there but latex is more forgiving)

Comment: That was fast! It works quite well, except... it's misplaced, I'm using `\DeclareCaptionListFormat{quadro}{#1#2 \textendash}'
... there is still a extra space after the endash and little space before.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I concentrated on the main issue -- not `\newinsert` ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer oh sorry hadn't noticed that came from the question:-)

Comment: @G.Bay: Sorry, I was misreading the order of `--` etc. I'll try to track the cause of the additional space.

Comment: @G.Bay: See the update please.

Comment: I really don't want to sound thankless, but still got issues. Now it's with double digit quadros, because the space set by dottedtocline counts from the margnig i guess but ignores the numbering.

Comment: @G.Bay: Well, actually you brought yourself in trouble with this `Quadro ... -- ` setup, but I provided a solution